# Implementation of LRU cache failing for one big test

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, hashmap

I have implemented an LRU cache that is passing for mostly all the cases but failing for one big test case that is hard to debug.

```
class LRUCache {
    Map<Integer, Node> map;
    Node head;
    Node tail;
    int capacity;
    int currentSize;
    public LRUCache(int capacity) {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.currentSize = 0;
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
    }

    public int get(int key) {
        if(map.containsKey(key)){
            Node node = map.get(key);
            removeNode(node);
            moveNodeAtTop(node);
            return node.value;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void put(int key, int value) {
        Node node = new Node(key, value);
        removeKey(key);
        if(map.size() == this.capacity && tail!=null){
            removeKey(tail.key);
        }
        moveNodeAtTop(node);
        map.put(key, node);
    }

    private void removeKey(int key){
       Node node = map.get(key);
        removeNode(node);
        map.remove(key);
    }

    public void removeNode(Node node){
        if (node == null) return;
        if (node.prev != null) {
            node.prev.next = node.next;

        }
        if (node.next != null) {
            node.next.prev = node.prev;
        }
        if (node == tail) {
            this.tail = node.prev;
        }
        if (node == head) {
            this.head = node.next;
        }
    }

    public void moveNodeAtTop(Node node){
        if(this.head == null){
            this.head = node;
            this.tail = node;
        }else{
            node.next = this.head;
            this.head.prev = node;
            head = node;
        }
    }

    private class Node{
        Node next;
        Node prev;
        int value;
        int key;
        Node(int key, int value){
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I saw some code on leetcode discuss, some people keep head and tail as dummy or -1. They treat head.next as head and tail.prev as the tail. All the test cases are passing on that code. Then I saw the cracking the coding interview book it's similar to my approach but on GitHub, they have another approach.

I know that by dummy head and tail, we can get rid of null. I think we can achieve the same with Optional. I just want to understand which test case is failing without a dummy head and tail.

**Working Solution**

```
    private Map<Integer, Node> map;
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int capacity;
    public LRUCache(int capacity) {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        this.capacity = capacity;
        head = new Node(-1, -1);
        tail = new Node(-1, -1);
        join(head, tail);
    }

    private void join(Node node1, Node node2){
        node1.next = node2;
        node2.prev = node1;
    }

    private void joinBetweenNode(Node node1, Node node2, Node node3){
        node2.prev = node1;
        node2.next = node3;
        node1.next.prev = node2;
        node1.next = node2;
    }

    public int get(int key) {
        if(map.containsKey(key)){
            Node node = map.get(key);
            removeNode(node);
            moveNodeAtTop(node);
            return node.value;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void put(int key, int value) {
        removeKey(key);
        if(map.size() == this.capacity && tail!=null){
            removeKey(getLast().key);
        }
        Node node = new Node(key, value);
        moveNodeAtTop(node);
        map.put(key, node);
    }

    private void removeKey(int key){
        Node node = map.get(key);
        removeNode(node);
        map.remove(key);
    }

    public void removeNode(Node node){
        if (node == null || node.prev == null || node.next == null) return;
        node.prev.next = node.next;
        node.next.prev = node.prev;
    }

    public void moveNodeAtTop(Node node){
      if(node == null) return;
      joinBetweenNode(head, node, head.next);
    }

    public Node getLast() {
        if (head.next == tail) {
            return null; // list has 0 Nodes
        }
        return tail.prev;
    }

    private class Node{
        Node next;
        Node prev;
        int value;
        int key;
        Node(int key, int value){
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

I am not sure why the first solution is failing for some edge cases.
In case if someone got to please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I have found the mistake in moveNodeAtTop, I have missed setting previous of new head to null `node.prev = null;`

Working solution on all the leetcode test cases:

```
class LRUCache {
    Map<Integer, Node> map;
    Node head;
    Node tail;
    int capacity;
    int currentSize;
    public LRUCache(int capacity) {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.currentSize = 0;
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
    }

    public int get(int key) {
        if(map.containsKey(key)){
            Node node = map.get(key);
            removeNode(node);
            moveNodeAtTop(node);
            return node.value;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void put(int key, int value) {
        Node node = new Node(key, value);
        removeKey(key);
        if(map.size() == this.capacity && tail!=null){
            removeKey(tail.key);
        }
        moveNodeAtTop(node);
        map.put(key, node);
    }

    private void removeKey(int key){
       Node node = map.get(key);
        removeNode(node);
        map.remove(key);
    }

    public void removeNode(Node node){
        if (node == null) return;
        if (node.prev != null) {
            node.prev.next = node.next;

        }
        if (node.next != null) {
            node.next.prev = node.prev;
        }
        if (node == tail) {
            this.tail = node.prev;
        }
        if (node == head) {
            this.head = node.next;
        }
    }

    public void moveNodeAtTop(Node node){
        if(this.head == null){
            this.head = node;
            this.tail = node;
        }else{
            node.next = this.head;
            this.head.prev = node;
            head = node;
            node.prev = null;
        }
    }

    private class Node{
        Node next;
        Node prev;
        int value;
        int key;
        Node(int key, int value){
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```